# Java access variable

Tags: java, class, variables, andengine

I have a problem trying to access to one variable I created in a diferent class.

I have a class GameScene where I create a new class:

```
npcArray[0] = new Npc(-100, 100, vbom, camera, physicsWorld, 0);
```

There in npcArray[0] I want access to a variable created in the previeus class.
How I can access it?

**Edit1:**

Class1:

```
public class GameScene extends BaseScene implements IOnSceneTouchListener, IOnAreaTouchListener {

    public Npc[] npcArray = new Npc[4];
    public Bullet[] bulletArray = new Bullet[500];
    public static Zombie[] zombieArray = new Zombie[50];

        //code...

private void createNPCs(){
        npcArray[0] = new Npc(-100, 100, vbom, camera, physicsWorld, 0);
        attachChild(npcArray[0]);
        registerTouchArea(npcArray[0]);
        npcArray[1] = new Npc(200, 100, vbom, camera, physicsWorld, 1);
        attachChild(npcArray[1]);
        registerTouchArea(npcArray[1]);
    }
```

Class 2:

```
public class Npc extends Sprite{

       //code...    

                if(distanciaMinima <= 3 && distanciaMinima != -1 && timer >= 200 ){
                    timer = 0;
                    Vector2 vectorUnitariBullet = new Vector2(GameScene.zombieArray[zombieProper].body.getPosition()).sub(body.getPosition()).nor();
                    GameScene.createBullet(ArrayPosition, vectorUnitariBullet, accuracy);
                }
}
```

So when I am to npcArray["number"] I want to access  the variable bulletArray or any method example: "GameScene.createBullet()" *now its wrong

**Edit2:**

My code structure reference this game: [Game Code](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-15.html) Download at the end

I'm trying to access a variable created in GameScene when I'm at Player.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: The question does not contain enough information to help.

Comment: How do you try to access it? what error does it gives? We need more information in order to help you

Comment: Off hand, I think this is a code smell. The way your code is being structured, you're going to end up with extremely tight coupling and I suspect poor encapsulation. That is going to make maintenance a nightmare. How you should refactor is hard to know, especially without an understanding of the full system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add GameScene reference to Npc. and edit your constructor.

```
Class Npc
{
   public GameScene gs;
   public Npc(int x, int y, ..... , GameScene gs)
   {
       this.gs = gs;   
   }
}
```

pass the game scene with the constructor by using this term:

```
npcArray[0] = new Npc(-100, 100, vbom, camera, physicsWorld, 0, this);
```

to access it:

```
npcArray[0].gs.variable_name
```

**Note** This will not cause additional memory allocations.

Comment: This kind of pattern always makes me cringe. Feels like you're breaking encapsulation or some related concept. No downvote, though, as I haven't got any better ideas.

Comment: A reference only to the variable :)